# iterating through open windows in wpf

Tags: wpf

i'm developing an application (wpf) that have 3 windows. in the main window user can open other window. when user wants to open window1 i'm create an instance of window1 and showing up that

```
var win1 = new Window1();
win1.Owner = this;
win1.Show();
```

now when user wants to close app, i want to iterate through each open window and check if that window isn't busy (or if is busy wait to complete operation) close that window and then close application. my question is how to iterating through open windows? maybe using this:

```
foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    window.
}
```

but how i can detect window is Window1 or Window2?

Comment: using var in the foreach statement won't help in getting access to each iteration's window properties; in order to do so, replace "var" with "Window" as seen in the following tut: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/849/wpf-application-windows-property.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
if(window is Window1)
{
   //window is of type 'Window1'!
}
```

Inside the 'foreach' loop.

Comment: ,Iam using Xbap application ,I want to loopthrough pages instead Window how to do this